# Core data in framework shows only one entity

Tags: objective-c, core-data, objective-c-framework

I'm trying to make my first framework for iOS.

I have core data in it, in my `xcdatamodel` I have two `entites`, I auto generated classes for both models, but when I print `[[managedObjectModel entities] valueForKey:@"name"]` I see only first entity.

Also when I try to `init fetchRequest withEntityName` of second entity I don't see it at all.

And the weirdest thing is that for first entity everything works perfectly. Also if I do updates inside first entity I can see it, so I believe that it has the latest version.

Comment: Have you delete your app from simulator after added new entity ??

Comment: @CodeChanger I am working on iPhone, but yea, I tried that, I also tried to remove preserve_paths in podspec file and then to put it back again, but same thing happens

Comment: can you please delete that app from iPhone and clean derived data and try agin.

Comment: @CodeChanger i just tried that, and its still same

Comment: you are creating static or dynamic framework ?

Comment: @CodeChanger dynamic framework

Comment: if I am not wrong than, you are using that framework in another project and there you didn't get 2nd entity.

Comment: @CodeChanger yes, that is the case.

Answer (score 0):

As per my experience I have used all private variable and it will not access out side `framework` so that may be the case.

or you one more thing you have to specify your `framework` core data `bundle` path so that that `entity` will access by current project in which you have used dynamic `framework`.

**Like this :**

```
lazy var managedObjectModel: NSManagedObjectModel = {
    // The managed object model for the application. This property is not optional. It is a fatal error for the application not to be able to find and load its model.
    let carKitBundle = NSBundle(identifier: "YOUR_FRAMEWORK_BUNDLE_PATH")

    let modelURL = carKitBundle!.URLForResource("YOUR_MODEL_NAME", withExtension: "momd")!
    return NSManagedObjectModel(contentsOfURL: modelURL)!
}()
```

may be it will help you to get your entity in current project.

Let me know if it will solve your problem.

Thanks.